# Force Internal Speakers Even If Headphones Are Plugged In

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to find a way of forcing sound to be routed through internal speakers of a computer—even if headphones are plugged in.

I've been working with `AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h`, but so far I've only been able to adjust the volume of current active output device.

Even if I can't route sound to a different device, is there a way to adjust the volume of a non-active output device? For example, I'd like to edit the volume of the internal speakers while headphones are plugged in.

Just for clarification, I'm trying to achieve this in OS X, not iOS.

Comment: I wont post as an actual answer because I don't know, but I would guess this is not possible. Maybe you have some interesting idea for an app, but as an end user it would seriously irritate me if my Mac made noise while my headphones were plugged in.

Comment: Well, I was also thinking of the end user, actually. What if the user wants that behavior to happen? Obviously, I'm not going to randomly play sounds when headphones are plugged in. There's a specific purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible (at least on the iMac line, but possible on others as well). I once even filed a bug with apple about that, but they answered that it works as intended and that they are not going to change this. The hardware (at least on my iMac again) is capable of this. I suggest you file a bug with Apple.